# Equivalence classes and subgroups of bijections of $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Consider the group $S_3 = Sym({1,2,3})$, which we recall is the group of all bijections from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$ and where the group operation is composition. We have seen that this group has order 6 and is not abelian. We let
>   [S3 equal this set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzDqG.png)
>
> For instance, $a_5$ is the function $a_5 : \{1,2,3\} \to \{1,2,3\}$ with $a_5(1) = 2, a_5(2) = 3,$ and $a_5(3) = 1$.
>
> (a) Explain in one or two sentences why $H = \{1,a_1\}$ is a subgroup of $S_3$.
>
> (b) Recall that there is an equivalence relation ~ defined in $S_3$ by $u$ ~ $v$ iff $uv^-1 \in H$. Find all the distinct equivalence classes for ~.
>
> (c)Which of the obtained equivalence classes are subgroups of $S_3$?

So for (a), I know that for each $x \in$ group compositioned with identity element yields $x$, so I know that 1 belongs in subset $\{1, a_1\}$, and same can be applied for $a_1$. But I do not know how to summarize that into a sentence.

For (b) and (c), I'm having trouble exactly what equivalence classes are... Are they just subsets that partition the group in 2?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Please note that simply copying your assignment, as if you were the one giving homework to us, is not generally well-received. If you would like help, please provide context for the problem, and indicate what you have attempted and exactly what your difficulties are. Otherwise, the question will be closed. Please edit the question to include this information.

Comment: Sorry, but what's  $a_1$?  It must have order $2$.

Comment: @Chris Custer it's explained in the photo

Comment: Okay.  So $a_1$ is the transposition $(12)$.  It does indeed have order $2$.  So you have a subgroup.

Comment: a) Because $a_1^2=1$, so $H \subseteq S_3$ is closed vs. group operation (composition).

Answer (score 1):

a) Because $a_1^2=1$, so $H⊆S_3$ is closed vs. group operation (=composition) and then $H \le S_3$.

b) The equivalence class of $v \in S_3$ is:

\begin{alignat}{1}
[v] &:= \{u \in S_3\mid u \sim v\} \\
&= \{u \in S_3\mid uv^{-1}\in H\} \\
&= \{u \in S_3\mid \exists h \in H:uv^{-1}=h\} \\
&= \{u \in S_3\mid \exists h \in H:u=hv\} \\
&= \{hv, h \in H\} \\
&=: Hv 
\end{alignat}

Since $H=\{1,a_1\}$, we get $Hv=\{v,a_1v\}$: from this, firstly you can get all the equivalence classes, then you can conclude that the class $Hv$ is a subgroup if (by a)) and only if (because $1$ must be in a subgroup) $v=1$ or $v=a_1$, and then $(H1=Ha_1=)H$ is the only equivalence class which is subgroup of $S_3$ (this is c)).

Answer (score 0):

Let's write out the elements of $S_3$.  They are $\{(12), (23), (13), (123), (132),e\}$.  (In the picture they are $a_1=(12), a_2=(23), a_3=(13), a_4=(132)$ and $a_5=(123)$.)

Now, it's clear that there are $3$ equivalence classes.  They are $[(12)]=\{e, (12)\}, [(13)]=\{(123),(13)\}$ and $[(23)]=\{(132), (23)\}$.  Only the first is a subgroup.